# Prettier extention formatting is going weird

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, word-wrap, prettier

When I write a long paragraph it looks normal. But after saving (formatting) it looks weird.
FYI word-wrapping and format on save was on.

This is before formatting
[image]

This is after formatting
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Okey, It's the window width. If I maximize vscode the promlem is gone.***

Answer (score 1):

VS code wraps long lines if they exceed a certain length if "format on save" is on. To disable it, set the maximum length to 0.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the `Preferences: Open JSON Settings` command. Add the following line:

```json
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0
```